# pass image from collectionView to tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uiimageview

i want to pass my imageview's image from a collection view cell that I loaded from my webservice to another tableview imageview. in prepare for segue i don't have access to my first Collection view cell to get my image view and pass to new tableviewController. if you have any idea please help me

Comment: Don't get data from the **view** (cell), get it always from the **model** (data source).

Comment: Pass the webservice response to the next view controller

Comment: i don't want to load data Twice from webservice

Comment: You can transfer response model to next controller , instead of calling web service. @AmirhosseinKhodaei